# Integration using assumption in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, polynomials, assumptions

I want to reproduce the solution of the following integral, using Mathematica: $$\int_0^1duu(1-u)^2\frac{1}{(1-u)(1-v)}\left(\frac{1-u}{u}(1+\frac{1}{1-v})\theta(u-v)+\frac{1-v}{v}(1+\frac{1}{1-u})\theta(v-u)\right)\left(2u-1\right)^n$$
 Basically this is a diagonalization of a kernel function in the interval $(0,1)$ with respect to the polynom $(2v-1)^n$ and weight $u(1-u)^2$. The variables $u$ and $v$ have to be in the $(0,1)$ interval. I know that the solution is this expression:
$\frac{1}{2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\sum_{m=0}^n \left((5+2n)(-1)^{n-m}+3+2m \right)\left( 2v-1\right)^m$.

I am writing this code in Mathematica, where I have split the integral into two parts because of the theta-function.

```
    I1 = Integrate[u*(1 - u)^2*(((1 - u)/u)*(1 + 1/(1 - v)))*
   ((2*u - 1)^n/((1 - u)*(1 - v))), {u, v, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers && n>0 && 0 < u < 1 && 0 < v < 1}]; 
  I2 = Integrate[u*(1 - u)^2*((1 - v)/v)*(1 + 1/(1 - u))*((2*u -  1)^n/((1 - u)*(1 - v))), 
  {u, 0, v}, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers && n>0 && 0 < u < 1 && 0 < v < 1}];
```

but I am not getting the right solution. I tried to subtract the solution I get from the analytic one and I do not get zero. Am I doing something wrong in the "Assumptions"-part in the code? The n is Natural number. I would deeply appreciate any help or insight.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 1):

```
I1 = Integrate[
u*(1 - u)^2*(((1 - u)/u)*(1 + 1/(1 - v)))*((2*u - 1)^
n/((1 - u)*(1 - v))), {u, v, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers && n > 0 && 0 < u < 1 && 0 < v < 1}];

I2 = Integrate[u*(1 - u)^2*((1 - v)/v)*(1 + 
1/(1 - u))*((2*u - 1)^n/((1 - u)*(1 - v))), {u, 0, v}, 
Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers && n > 0 && 0 < u < 1 && 0 < v < 1}];

ans1 = FullSimplify[I1 + I2][[1]]
```

> $\frac{5 (-1)^n v^2+(4 v-5) (2 v-1)^{n+2}-10 (-1)^n v+2 n (v-1) \left((2 v-1)^{n+2}+(-1)^n
>    (v-1)\right)+5 (-1)^n-v^2+2 v}{4 (n+1) (n+2) (n+3) (v-1)^2 v}$

In the above I used `[[1]]` after `FullSimplify[I1 + I2`] to extract the answer from the conditional expression.

While Integrate will sometimes give answers that include special functions that represent series (e.g., the polylogarithm function), it favors closed-form solutions, as seen above.  Thus, to check equivalence, we need to convert your solution to closed form:

```
ans2 = 1/(2 (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3)) Sum[((5 + 2 n) (-1)^(n - m) + 3 + 2 m)*(2 v - 1)^m, {m, 0, n}] // FullSimplify
```

> $\frac{5 (-1)^n v^2+(4 v-5) (2 v-1)^{n+2}-10 (-1)^n v+2 n (v-1) \left((2 v-1)^{n+2}+(-1)^n
>    (v-1)\right)+5 (-1)^n-v^2+2 v}{4 (n+1) (n+2) (n+3) (v-1)^2 v}$

```
ans1===ans2
```

> $True$

Answer (score 0):

Using `Boole` you can integrate in one step and get the analytic result without warnings:

```
lsg = Integrate[(
u*(1 - u)^2)/((1 - u)*(1 -v))*(((1 - u)/u) (1 + 1/(1 - v)) Boole[u >= v] + ((1 - v)/v) (1 + 1/(1 - u)) Boole[u < v])*(2*u - 1)^n, {u, 0, 1}
, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers && n > 0, 0 < v < 1}] //FullSimplify
(*(5 (-1)^n + 2 v - 10 (-1)^n v - v^2 + 5 (-1)^n v^2 + (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n) (-5 + 4 v) +2 n (-1 + v) ((-1)^n (-1 + v) + (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n)))/(4 (1 +n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (-1 + v)^2 v)*)
```

**addendum**

solution in terms of 2v-1 ?
->substitution/resubstitution evaluates to

```
Collect[lsg /. v -> (vn + 1)/2, vn^k_] /. vn -> 2 v - 1
(*(3/4 + (5 (-1)^n)/4 + 1/2 (-1)^n n + 1/2 (-1 + 2 v) - 
5/2 (-1)^n (-1 + 2 v) + (-1)^(1 + n) n (-1 + 2 v) - 
1/4 (-1 + 2 v)^2 + 5/4 (-1)^n (-1 + 2 v)^2 + 
1/2 (-1)^n n (-1 + 2 v)^2 - 3 (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n) - 
n (-1 + 2 v)^(2 + n) + 2 (-1 + 2 v)^(3 + n) + 
n (-1 + 2 v)^(3 + n))/(4 (1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (-1 + v)^2 v)*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code produced a neat answer. I do have another question: Is there a way in Mathematica to bring this answer in the same form as the analytic one, which includes series? Or am I asking too much? Eventually I will have to write this answer as a polynomial in (2v-1) and extract the coefficients. This is an eigenvalue problem that's why.

Comment: The result is an analytic answer (without series)! The Sum you gave as analytical expression evaluates to the result which MMA found.